# Creating Excel Table

Tags: laravel

How can I create a table from excel sheet when I import it with Laravel by the way I'm using laravel-excel package and I want to create it instantly with the importing which means creating new table.

versions of packages I'm using it is :

Laravel 6

Laravel-excel maatwebsite 3.1

Comment: Please provide some details of what you tried and what problem you got stuck on.

Comment: I've imported data using this library, and after that the primitive way for get data is by array, so then you can define your scheme.